# Tried out the Binary Tree Inorder Traversal using recursive. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: python, binary-tree, inorder

Test cases passes individually, but when submitted, the first Output just stays in the list.

Cant wrap my head around it. What is happening?

```
class Solution:

l=[]

def inorderTraversal(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[int]:

    if root is None:
        return self.l
    else:
        if root.left:
            self.inorderTraversal(root.left)
        self.l.append(root.val)
        if root.right:
            self.inorderTraversal(root.right)

        return self.l

***Test Case***

> Your input [1] 
Output [1] 

Expected [1]

**Submitted**

> Wrong Answer Details 
Input [] 
Output [1,3,2] 
Expected []
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you do not initialize `l` in a constructor `__init__(self)`
By declaring `l` the way you did, it will be shared by all the instance of `Solution`. This most probably your problem since the testing code probably instantiates a new `Solution` for every case.

Your could add the following to your solution class to ensure that l is not shared by the `Solution` instances:

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.l=[]
```

If it still does not work, the class solution is probably instantiated once and the method `inorderTraversal` is probably called on each test inputs

In this case you have to slightly to change you `inorderTraversal`:

```py
def inorderTraversal(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[int]:
    result = []
    if root is None:
        return result
    else:
        if root.left:
            result.extend(self.inorderTraversal(root.left))
        result.append(root.val)
        if root.right:
            result.extend(self.inorderTraversal(root.right))

        return result
```

and you can simplify the code to:

```py
def inorderTraversal(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[int]:
    result = []
    if root.left:
        result.extend(self.inorderTraversal(root.left))
    result.append(root.val)
    if root.right:
        result.extend(self.inorderTraversal(root.right))

     return result
```